# VerQueryValue not returning copyright symbol in Chinese OS?

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, delphi-7

I am trying to display EXE information using `VerQueryValue` in Chinese Simplified OS. All the text is displayed correctly, but the copyright symbol is displayed as "?" . Here is the code which i am using.

```
   const
     CInfoStr : array[1..13] of string =
('FileVersion',
 'CompanyName',
 'FileDescription',
 'InternalName',
 'LegalCopyright',
 'LegalTradeMarks',
 'OriginalFileName',
 'ProductName',
 'ProductVersion',
 'Comments',
 'CurrentProgramVersion',
 'CurrentDatabaseVersion',
 'VersionDetails');

type

  PTransBuffer = ^TTransBuffer;
  TTransBuffer = array[1..13] of smallint;


Function CheckFileVerForAppReplaceAlert(Path : String): Boolean;
var
  InfoSize,
  VerSize, Wnd : DWORD;
  Value        : PChar;
  ValWide      : PWideCHar;
  NewValWide   : WideString;
  VerBuf       : pointer;
  pTrans       : PTransBuffer;
  TypeStr,
  TransStr     : string;
  j            : Integer;

  KeyPath      : String;
  NewFileVer   : String;
  OldFileVer   : String;

  ResVer : Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  If Path = '' then
    exit;
 try
   // Get Version of File
    InfoSize := GetFileVersioninfoSize(PChar(Path), Wnd);
   if (InfoSize <> 0) then
   begin
     try
       GetMem(VerBuf, InfoSize);
       if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(Path), Wnd, InfoSize, VerBuf) then
       begin
         if VerQueryValue(VerBuf, PChar('\VarFileInfo\Translation'),Pointer(pTrans), VerSize) then
        begin
        TransStr := IntToHex(pTrans^[1], 4) + IntToHex(pTrans^[2], 4);
        TypeStr := 'StringFileInfo\' + TransStr + '\' + CInfoStr[5];   //Get The Copyright
        //if VerQueryvalue(VerBuf, PChar(TypeStr),Pointer(Value), VerSize) then
        if VerQueryvalue(VerBuf, PChar(TypeStr),Pointer(Value), VerSize) then
        begin
          NewFileVer := Value;
          //NewValWide :=Value;
          Updatelog('NewFileVer ' + NewValWide);
         // ShowMessage('Copyright ' + NewFileVer);
          //MessageBoxW(Application.Handle, PWideCHar(NewFileVer) , PWideChar('Err'),MB_OKCANCEL);
        end;

      end;
    end
  finally
    Try
      FreeMem(VerBuf, InfoSize);
    Except
    End;
  end;
end  //end Of taking version
 except
 end;
end;
```

Here is the code written for the widestring ones :

```
 Function AddWidePathToAppList_Reg(AppPath : WideString): Boolean ;
 Var
   j : Integer;
   PathWS : WideString;
   InfoSize,VerSize, Wnd: DWORD;
   pTrans: PTransBuffer;
   VerBuf: pointer;
   VerFlag: Boolean;
   Value: PWChar;
   TypeStr,
   TransStr: WideString;
 Begin
   Result := False;
   PathWS := (AppPath);
      InfoSize := GetFileVersioninfoSizeW(PWChar(AppPath), Wnd);
      if (InfoSize <> 0) then
      begin
          GetMem(VerBuf, InfoSize);
          try
              if GetFileVersionInfoW(PWChar(AppPath), Wnd, InfoSize, VerBuf) then
              begin
                  if VerQueryValueW(VerBuf, '\VarFileInfo\Translation',Pointer(pTrans), VerSize) then
                  begin
                      VerFlag:=False;
                      TransStr := IntToHex(pTrans^[1], 4) + IntToHex(pTrans^[2], 4);
                      for j := Low(CInfoStr) to High(CInfoStr) do
                      begin
                          TypeStr := 'StringFileInfo\' + TransStr + '\' + CInfoStr[j];
                          if VerQueryvalueW(VerBuf, PWChar(TypeStr),Pointer(Value), VerSize) then
                          begin
                             UpdateLog('Vlaue ' + Value);
                             Result := True;
                          end;
                      end;
                  end;
              end;
          finally
              FreeMem(VerBuf, InfoSize);
          end;
      end;

 end;
```

I dont understand what am i doing wrong. I tried using WideString in place of String. But it makes no difference.

Guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: check that your `UpdateLog` is Unicode also. you might be getting the right results via `VerQueryValueW` but reading them wrong. just saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That a `?` is returned indicates that the system converted from UTF-16 to ANSI and failed due to the character not being present in your ANSI code page. You are using an ANSI version of Delphi and so this is expected behaviour.

In order to read out the UTF-16 you are going to have to call the Unicode variants of the API functions. These are the functions that are suffixed with `W`. So, instead of calling `VarQueryValue`, which maps to `VarQueryValueA` (the 8 bit ANSI variant), call `VarQueryValueW`.

You'll need to pass pointers to `WideChar` arrays. The easiest way to do that is using `WideString` and then casting to `PWideChar`.

It's not clear what you will do with this symbol once you have it in a `WideChar`. The system was unable to convert it to your ANSI code page, that being impossible, and you've got no better hope of succeeding. So you'd need to using Unicode controls to display the text.

You claim that you have attempted what I describe above, and still see the `?` character. That can only happen if your debugging mechanism is also limited to your ANSI code page.

Comment: When you call `VarQueryValueW`, how are you displaying the output? Since you are writing an ANSI program, in an ANSI IDE, you won't be able to display characters that are not in your ANSI character set. Did you try `MessageBoxW` as your debugging method?

Comment: Thanks David. MessageBoxW displayed the correct output. I will proceed with the solution.